# Automated Email invoice error when i call spreadsheet name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to automate my Google sheet to be sent to my email every month.
But looks like I have a problem calling the spreadsheet

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName("Invoice test");   
  var filename = "Current Month " + ss.getName();
  var SendBook = ss.copy(filename);
  var ToUser = "example@gmail.com";
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: ToUser,
    subject: 'Invoice for last month',
    body: 'Hi! I have attached my invoice for this month. ',
    attachments: [SendBook.getBlob().setName(filename)]
  });
}
```

if I remove "`.getName("Invoice test");`" I receive all the spreadsheets in one email, I only want the first page.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName("Invoice test");
```

by

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Invoice test");
```

[documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)) or to just select the first sheet:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
```

[documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)